# How to get chrome to check e-tag/cache headers on PHP 302 redirect

Tags: php, redirect, caching, http-status-code-302, etag

I have a PHP page that performs a 302 redirect to another php page on the box, the new page returns cache/e-tag headers.

If the second page has modifications / new e-tag, chrome doesn't pick these up via the 302 redirect - you have to refresh the browser once at the page, or navigate to it directly.

How do I get it to check for modifications if sent their via the 302?

Interestingly, I cant see the request for the redirect page in charles.  I see the initial request, and it comes back with the header for the new page, but there is no log for the new page - Is that because its technically part of the same request?

m

UPDATE: some examples...

**Request** for first URL

```
GET /preview/slide/379 HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.co.uk
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6
```

**Response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 11:51:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://domain.co.uk/preview/index.html?manifest=e232715f805d23bb657a644679d4beaf.json
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And then there is NO subsequent request sent by chrome, it just serves the file from disk.

However, if you go to the location directly, you get.

**Request**

```
GET /preview/index.html?manifest=e232715f805d23bb657a644679d4beaf.json HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.co.uk
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6
If-None-Match: "ab186261accfe1a5a8de8306ff8e56b9"
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 20 Oct 2015 13:31:09 GMT
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 11:59:05 GMT
Server: Apache
ETag: "ab186261accfe1a5a8de8306ff8e56b9"
```

So it basically just serves the file from disk if it has one, sounds like aggressive caching from chrome.

Is there a header I can set in the 302 redirect to make it then check the server again?

Comment: It would be helpful if showed us the response from the first page and the headers from the second.

Comment: @symcbean Ive added some examples, sorry.

Comment: In the absence of "must-revalidate" in the cache-control header, the browser can use a stale response from its cache. Also, be warned, these are the headers currently being returned, different ones (with more positive caching information) may have been returned in the past.

Comment: thanks @symcbean - I got to the answer at the same time!  If you want to post that as an answer Ill accept it....

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of "must-revalidate" in the cache-control header, the browser can use a stale response from its cache.

Comment: chrome is not revalidating regardless.

Answer (score -2):

Hello first enable error reporting in your page after 302 redirection please add exit command.

If you can see the error then resolve that error. Chrome some time will not redirect the page if there is some content are display / printed before the redirection.

Comment: There are no errors, and chrome is following the redirect.  Its just not checking any cache headers to see if there is a newer version of the file that it is redirecting too.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question as OP doesn't mention failing redirect.

Comment: yes, same here. it is ignoring it. this makes relying on etag kind of pointless.

Comment: @mmm can you please share link or some code snippet so i will help you